# Xcode 15 Beta: Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode

When I build my iOS project on Xcode 15 Beta 3, I get these build warnings:

```
Duplicate -rpath '/usr/lib/swift' ignored
Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
```

On Xcode 14 I didn't get them, so I guess it's something related to new Xcode 15 linker.

Does anyone know if it can/should be fixed and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To prevent this warning in Xcode 15, add `-ld_classic` in Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 2):

We have same new `ld` warnings with Xcode 15 Beta 6. After investigation, we found that they are generated by third-party libraries.
I created [issue](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/AppsFlyerFramework/issues/251) for one of them, where I described how I found out which code generates these warnings. Maybe it will be useful for you.

If this is in your code, I think it will be easy to find duplicates and remove them in build settings (`LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` parameter or similar)

Answer (score 2):

I have added -ld64 to Other Linker Flags and my problem is solved.
for this go to Target -> Build Setting -> search for other linker flags

Comment: XCode has an explicit warning for that: "-ld64 is deprecated, use -ld_classic instead" :)))